# How to compare data while fetching from URL using PHP

Tags: php

I am fetching some data from URL and comparing those through `if` statement but it's not happening like that. My code is below:

```
localhost/spesh/user.php?action='signup'
```

I am typing the above url and run.

> user.php:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['action'])){
   $act=$_REQUEST['action'];
   if($act=='signup'){
     echo 'hii';
   }
}
```

Here I can not print the echo message while calling that URL.

Comment: at the top of your script, do `echo file_get_contents('php://input')` and show us what you see.

Comment: No value is coming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `'signup'` as parameter value and if you access `$_REQUEST['action']` it returns `'signup'`. You should use your url as `localhost/spesh/user.php?action=signup`

Comment: @satya remember to select the answer that solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

remove single quotes form your url like,

```
localhost/spesh/user.php?action=signup
```

**OR**

When using the same url use this code, the action variable contain `'signup'` (with single quotes),

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['action'])){
   $act=$_REQUEST['action'];
   if($act=="'signup'"){
     echo 'hii';
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get request of query strings value with global $_GET variable,

```php
$_GET['action'];
```